# Trying to add event handler to dynamic content using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add an onclick event handler to a list of checkboxes.  Instead of alerting the checkbox ID that I would expect it to (the one I'm clicking on), it's always alerting checkbox number 3 regardless of which on I click.   Why is this and how can I get this to behave as desired.  When I click on checkbox 2, I want it to alert "2"... etc.

```
function component (componentId, displayType, parentId) {
    this.componentId = componentId;
    this.parentId = parentId;
    this.displayType = displayType;
}
var components = [];

components.push(new component(0, null, null);
components.push(new component(1, null, null);
components.push(new component(2, null, null);
components.push(new component(3, null, null);


var arrayLength = components.length;
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    var component = components[i];
    jQuery('#questionnaireComponentId'+component.componentId).find('input:checkbox').click(
        function(){
            selectParentCheckbox(component.componentId);
            }
    );
}

function selectParentCheckbox(componentId){
    alert(componentId);
}
```

Comment: can you share your generated html as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because of the [Javascript closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work).

You should pass the parameter each iteration, and not only after finishing the iteration.

```
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    var component = components[i];
    jQuery('#questionnaireComponentId' + component.componentId)
      .find('input:checkbox')
      .click(selectParentCheckbox.bind(null, component.componentId));
}
```

The [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) function allows you to name what the function the click event will be calling and what parameters should be passed to it.

---

Nothing to do with the question, but only for your information: I think you're misunderstanding the power of [jQuery and its event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/), since you could use a much better aproach at all.

Comment: Works great!  Thank you.  And that link was very helpful and informative as well.  Although, I'm still now sure how to use that info for a better solution to this particular problem but I'm still thinking about it and have few ideas to try.